FIR filter: settling time and group delay
I have a question in the context of group delay and settling time in the context of FIR filter, especially for minimum-phase filter.
The settling time for a FIR filter of length N is N-1. Obviously it will be longer compared to the group delay (N-1)/2, and especially for a minimum-phase version of the same FIR filter.
Here an example of the impulse response of a linear-phase fir and its minimum phase:

The length of the filter is N=100.
Next we see the step response for these filters:

As expected the minimum-phase has an immediate response compared to the linear phase, and both have the same settling time.
What irretates me is the behavior in the context of a single tone (in the passband of the filter).

It can be seen that the amplitude and phase for both filters are distored at the begining, however, it seems that the steady state is reached before the settling time.
In the context of applications where the signal to evaluate is rather short itself, and an immediate evaluation is needed, discarding many samples due to the settling time is undesirable.
So my question, assuming the input is a mix of multiple tones and noise, would it be enough (or what are the risks) to wait only for the number of group delay samples (especially for minimum-phase) to evaluate the output or are theses samples not reliable at all and we always should wait until the filter is settled? Or is there a compromise between these two values?
EDIT:
Inspired by Hilmars answers, an additional question is:
How can the accuracy be evaluated/quantified depended on frequency and number of samples(K which are smaller than N-1 ) for a given filter?

If you want to go fast, minimum phase is definitely they way to go.

would it be enough (or what are the risks) to wait only for the number of group delay samples (especially for minimum-phase)

For minimum phase, the group delay is frequency dependent so you can't put single number on it. For both filter types the output transitions to the steady state response over N samples, however the minimum phase gets "close" to the final answer much quicker. How long you need to wait depends and how "precise" your answer needs to be. In your example, for the minimum phase filter the amplitude will be within 1 dB of the final answer within maybe 20-ish samples. For the linear phase this takes at least 60 samples.
So it's a trade off between accuracy and speed. This trade off will depend on the requirements of your specific application.

Thank you for your answer, is there a way to evaluate/quantify the accuracy depended on frequency and number of samples for a given filter?

Could we just evaluate the passband ripples of frequency response of the truncate set of coefficients. Having the minimum-phase coeff b_minphase(1:N), the frequency response of  b_minphase(1:K) with K<N would be calculated?

Again, that depends a lot on what exactly want to do with the signal. You can certainly analyze the truncated response, but whether this is the right or best method depends on your requirements and application.

Thank you for your response. I understand that the method for measuring the accuracy of a signal depends on the specific requirements and application. In the case of evaluating the magnitude and phase of different tones, are there specific methods or techniques that are commonly used for this type of analysis?
